# Artifacts between yellow and white of DNG image

Tags: adobe-camera-raw, dng

I have problems with DNG to TIFF conversion. When converting via Photoshop Camera Raw, there's a weird artifact on my yellow wall. What seems to fix it is changing the tint but it messes up the colors so much that it's unfixable with temperature. Also, I have tried many DNG color profiles, all of them have this issue.

Here's with correct tint and temperature:

[image]

Here's with tint turned up (that fixes the artifact but colors are messed up):
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, so just a comment for now, but that looks to me like an area where one (or maybe two) channels are clipped at maximum, which loses some information and results in odd results when you try to do various adjustments - look at the separate histograms for each channel to see if that's the case...

Comment: What's your actual input file type? What profile does Photoshop see when you import the DNG & what profile are you using at Export? Also - what profile do you have set as your Working Space & Colour Management Properties [Edit menu>color settings]?

Comment: Here is the image corrected by my (white balance). I use white package plastic for this purpose. Check if this is better for your purpose. https://imgur.com/a/EUwCm5Y

Comment: @twalberg Yes, the [histogram in that area](https://imgur.com/pN9jgm4) is quite funky The range of values for Ref and Green are very narrow compared to Blue.

Comment: the histogram isn't surprising for such a large swathe of single colour. Nothing's hit the top.

Comment: Can you provide the `dng` file you're working with?  What are the lighting sources for the image?

Comment: @Tetsujin You can take an image with clipping and reduce the output to make the clipped pixels less than "255", so just because the final image doesn't have anything at max doesn't mean the raw file wasn't clipped.

Comment: Or the clipping could have come when the original raw data from the sensor was converted to DNG, which can (depending on the implementation of the specific DNG convertor) "bake in" a white point that can potentially be below full saturation in the raw data from the sensor.

Comment: If it was clipped, I'd expect the white packing bottom right to be blown out, no matter what else had been done to it. I still think it's a profile/workflow issue - but we don't have the original to check. I'd like to see the 'true' original. before its conversion to DNG.